# How can I delete directories based on their numeric name value with a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, rm

I have a directory that contains numerically named subdirectories ( eg. 1, 2, 3, 32000, 43546 ).  I need to delete all directories over a certain number.  For example, I need to delete all subdirectories that have a name that is numerically larger than 14234.  Can this be done with a single command line action?

```
rm -r /directory/subdirectories_over_14234 ( how can I do this? )
```

Comment: Good question.  How can I determine this?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` is a first step, or `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do a bash for loop instruction so as to iterate over the directory filename and use the **test** command then after extracting the target number of the file name.

Should be something like this :

```
for $file in /your/path 
do
   #extract number here with any text processing command (ed ?)
   if test [$name -leq your_value]
   then
      rm -R $file
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

In bash, I'd write

```
for dir in *; do [[ -d $dir ]] && (( dir > 14234 )) && echo rm -r $dir; done
```

Remove the `echo` at your discretion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which shell you're using. I'm using [Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) and it has a very cool feature: it can select files based on numbers just like you want! So you can do

```
$ rm -r /directory/<14234->(/)
```

to select all the subdirectories of `/directory` with a numeric value over 14234.

In general, you use

```
<a-b>
```

to select paths with a *numeric values* between `a` and `b`. You append a `(/)` to only match *directories*. Use `(.)` to only match *files*. The [glob patterns](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) in Zsh are very powerful and can mostly (if not always) replace the good old `find` command.